# Restore EaseUS Todo Backup PBD to VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, easeus-todo-backup

I'm hoping someone can offer some assistance - I'm trying to restore a PBD backup file (containing a full OS and system backup - made using EaseUS Todo Backup) to a blank/new VirtualBox VM, and can't seem to get anywhere.  The PBD file was originally on an external USB drive, and while I could get the blank/new VM to see the external USB drive via enabling USB in the VM settings, it then wouldn't see the WinPE ISO file I'd attached to the VM in order to be able to do something with the PBD file.

I then tried to move the PBD file to a new hard drive VDI file I'd created, figuring I could attach this VDI, another VDI that would ultimately be where the PBD file contents were restored to (and be the primary hard drive of the VM), and the EaseUS WinPE ISO (in order to facilitate the restore), but this didn't work either (I can't quite remember what didn't work when trying this, as by this point it was getting late and I was getting tired and running out of steam).

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to accomplish this?  I had thought this would be relatively easy, but it seems like it isn't unless I'm just overlook something simple (which is likely).  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: off the top of my head, did you tick on the "livecd/dvd" box on virtualbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EaseUS Todo Backup can convert a PBD file to VMware format (VMDK) which is usable by VirtualBox.
Unfortunately, if you are using EaseUS Todo Backup Free then it doesn't support this
function for converting images.

1. Open the PBD file in EaseUS Todo Backup
2. Click Advanced
3. Select Convert image.
4. Select the disk or partition image file you want to convert.
5. Select the location to save image file, enter name and then select the format type
   as VMware.
6. Select location and format type
7. Click Proceed.

Comment: Tried converting to both VMware and Virtual PC (vhd) formats and it failed - see error message here: https://imgur.com/WZNAb6P

Comment: This is then another condition : The image should not include a GPT or DYNAMIC partition. Sorry, you are out of luck, as only EaseUS Todo Backup supports the PBD format. You may need to create a new system image of the disk using a product that creates it in a better-known format. Or create a Windows VM and try to use EaseUS Todo Backup to restore the image from inside the VM.

Comment: Can you even restore a EaseUS PBD backup from within a running OS?

Comment: You can [according to EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/restore-image.html). If it doesn't work for the system drive, you might need to define in the VM a second disk and restore to it, then make it the main disk. I don't guarantee that there won't be any EaseUS gotcha here as well. I personally use [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) which is free and without gotchas.

Comment: harrymc - any chance you can maybe provide some more info about the benefits of AOMEI Backupeer Freeware?  Thanks!

Comment: Read the excellent documentation. It's a wonderful product that compares well with commercial products, and it's free!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just taking a laptop I wasn't using, popping a spare SSD into it, and restoring the PBD file to that laptop using the EaseUS WinPE Emergency Disk.  Got it started up in Win10 Safe Mode and was able to get all the info I needed.  Wish there was an easy way to do this with VirtualBox, but guess not...

Although next time if I don't grab the entire disk to backup but just partitions, I might be able to use a non-free version of EaseUS Todo Backup to convert the PBD partition backup to a VMDK or VHD file (see above)